# Java Maven Issue

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

This is my pom.xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>org.javaee7.batch</groupId>
   <artifactId>batch-samples</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <name>Batch Applications for the Java Platform (JSR-352) Example</name>
   <description>Batch Applications for the Java Platform (JSR-352) Example</description>
   <url>http://jboss.org/jbossas</url>
   <licenses>
      <license>
         <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
         <distribution>repo</distribution>
         <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
      </license> 
   </licenses>
   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <version.jboss.maven.plugin>7.4.Final</version.jboss.maven.plugin>
      <version.jboss.spec.javaee.6.0>3.0.2.Final</version.jboss.spec.javaee.6.0>
      <version.war.plugin>2.1.1</version.war.plugin>
      <version.compiler.plugin>2.3.1</version.compiler.plugin>
      <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
      <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
      <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
      <version.jboss.bom>1.0.4.Final</version.jboss.bom>
   </properties>
   <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Beta2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.bom}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Import the Batch API which is included in WildFly 8 -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.batch</groupId>
         <artifactId>jboss-batch-api_1.0_spec</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Import the CDI API -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
         <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250) -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
         <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Import the Servlet API -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
         <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <!-- Set the name of the war, used as the context root when the app is deployed -->
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
               <!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
               <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <!-- JBoss AS plugin to deploy war -->
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.jboss.maven.plugin}</version>
         </plugin>
         <!-- Compiler plugin enforces Java 1.6 compatibility and activates 
                annotation processors -->
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.compiler.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
               <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
               <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>`
```

In eclipse I am getting below errors : 
1)

```
`Project build error: Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to transfer org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-7.0:pom:1.0.0.Beta2 from http://
 repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed  or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-7.0:pom:1.0.0.Beta2 from/to central (http:// repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/spec/jboss-javaee-7.0/1.0.0.Beta2/jboss-javaee-7.0-1.0.0.Beta2.pom`
```

Same type of error I am getting for `jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate`

2) I am also getting `Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar is missing.`

3) Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar is missing.

4) Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar is missing.

5) Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar is missing.

6) Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:jar is missing.

7)

```
`Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (execution: 
     default-compile, phase: compile)
    - CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1 or one of its dependencies 
     could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.1: ArtifactResolutionException: 
     Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.1 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local 
     repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer 
     artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to http://
     repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.3.1/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.1.pom
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:testCompile (execution: 
     default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)`
```

Please suggest.

Complete Error:

```
`[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/spec/jboss-javaee-7.0
/1.0.0.Beta2/jboss-javaee-7.0-1.0.0.Beta2.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/bom/jboss-javaee-6.0-
with-hibernate/1.0.4.Final/jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate-1.0.4.Final.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.javaee7.batch:batch-samples:1.0-SNAPSHOT (D:\Projects\
SID\POC\chunk-csv-database\chunk-csv-database\pom.xml) has 7 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.spe
c:jboss-javaee-7.0:pom:1.0.0.Beta2 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org
/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org @ line 31, column 22: Unknown host repo.maven.ap
ache.org -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.bom
:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-hibernate:pom:1.0.4.Final from/to central (http://repo.ma
ven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org @ line 38, column 22: Unknown host
 repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate.javax.persistenc
e:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar is missing. @ line 48, column 19
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate:hibernate-valida
tor:jar is missing. @ line 53, column 19
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar i
s missing. @ line 71, column 19
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.annotatio
n:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar is missing. @ line 77, column 19
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:j
boss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:jar is missing. @ line 83, column 19
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildin
gException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableMo
delException`
```

Comment: Try `mvn clean install -U` . This will force artifacts update from remote repositories.

Comment: Done but getting [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.javaee7.batch:batch-samples:1.0-SNAPSHOT (D:\Projects\
SID\POC\chunk-csv-database\chunk-csv-database\pom.xml) has 7 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.spe
c:jboss-javaee-7.0:pom:1.0.0.Beta2 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org
/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org @ line 31, column 22: Unknown host repo.maven.ap
ache.org -> [Help 2]

Comment: Getting this as well : [ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.hibernate:hibernate-valida
tor:jar is missing. @ line 53, column 19
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar i
s missing. @ line 71, column 19
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.annotatio
n:jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec:jar is missing. @ line 77, column 19
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:j
boss-servlet-api_3.0_spec:jar is missing. @ line 83, column 19

Comment: You did not provide `version` for some of your dependencies. And some of the artifacts you're trying to get are not available in Maven Central repo. You have to find Maven repo with these artifacts and add it in `<repositories>` tag in your pom.

Comment: Try to delete a corresponding folder in your local .m2 repository and build with -U afterwards.

Comment: Try to add this one as a repository: `https://repository.jboss.org/nexus`.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall/proxy perhaps?

Comment: I have edited my question with complete ERROR trace

Comment: @ Anders R. Bystrup ; when I try accessing http://central.maven.org/maven2/ then getting "Browsing for this directory has been disabled"..may be firewall..

Comment: @ lpratlong : where to add this.plz help

Comment: Add a `repository` tag. See http://maven.apache.org/pom.html

Answer (score 3):

From the stacktrace:

```
Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org
```

Regardless of the other comments, if you can't resolve the central repo you're not going to be able to download the dependencies.

Are you able to ping this from the command line (or at least get an IP for it)?

Comment: The pom.xml provided above builds perfectly OK with a clean repo and default settings.xml